# Why package object implicit members are visible to subpackage in some cases?

Tags: scala, package

Let's consider the following package hierarchy :

```
test
  --foo
    --Foo.scala
  --bar
    --Bar.scala
  package.scala
```

If one have the following code in the package object of `test` :

```
package object test {
    implicit class Pipe[A](a: A) {
      def |>[B](f: A => B): B = f(a)
    }
}
```

Then a case class in Foo.scala (in the package `test.foo`) :

```
package test.foo

case class Foo(i: Int)

object Foo {
    2.0 |> math.floor // 1 - Does not compile, package object is not visible
}
```

And finally the App in the package `test.bar` :

```
package test.bar

import test.foo.Foo

object Bar extends App {

    def plus2(i: Int) = i + 2
    def plus2(f: Foo) = f.i + 2
    def plus2(o: Option[Foo]) = o.map(f => Foo(f.i + 2))

    println(2 |> plus2) // 2 - Does not compile, package object is not visible
    println(Foo(2) |> plus2) // 3 - Does compile !?
    println(Option(Foo(2)) |> plus2) // 4 - Does compile too !?

}
```

The first two comments show us lines that do not compile, which is the expected behaviour because the package object is not visible in any subpackage.

Why do the third and forth cases compile ? Why is the implicit conversion applied in those cases ? We are not using a class of the root package (Foo is in a subpackage and Option is not in the package at all) neither are we importing the root package.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by when **implicits** defined in `package object`, these **implicits** will only work for a type prefixed by that package. for your example is type `Foo`.

so for your problem, you can manually import **implicits**, like:

```
import test._
println(2 |> plus2)
println(Foo(2) |> plus2)
```

Find More:

> Note that packages are internally represented as classes with companion modules to hold the package members. Thus, implicits defined in a package object are part of the implicit scope of a type prefixed by that package.

http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/07-implicits.html

Comment: Yes you're right, that's actually what I did ! I was curious about this particular case, and another one stranger : if the value used is now of type Future[Foo] or Option[Foo] etc. It still works, but Future/Option are not prefixed by the package ! I will edit my question to add this case.